# "not a database file" error accessing SQLite file

Tags: system.data.sqlite

I am having the same problem as of this guy,
[Error accesing SQLite file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938443/error-accesing-sqlite-file)

Can anyone tell what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed now. I used the "Migrate to SQLite3" in SQLite Administrator to re-saving the same DB file and it fixed the problem.